# Update top space constraint for view after hide search bar view

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, autolayout

I have custom UIView and UISearchBar that are placed as subviews on view controller view.

In some case I need hide search bar view and then I want to resize my custom view. So let's say that search bar has 44 pt of height. If it's visible at the top then my custom view should start with y = 44. But if I set search bar hidden, then my custom view should have y position equal to 0.

I use storyboard and I set all constraints, right I want to update top space constraint that is connected to top layout guide right now. By the default it equal 44 pt. But when I hide my search bar I want set top space to 0 and increase height of custom view by 44 pt.

I suppose that all subviews of the custom view will be updated automatically.

this is how views places on self.view of view controller:

```
***************
**search bar***
***************
**custom view**
***************
```

After hide search bar it should look like this and entirely overlay superview:

```
***************
**           **
**custom view**
**           **
***************
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hide **search bar** then create the outlets of Height constraint and Top space constraint as like below.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *searchBarTopSpaceHeight;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *searchBarHeight;
```

and set those values to 0 like as

```
_searchBarTopSpaceHeight.constant = 0;

_searchBarHeight.constant = 0;
```

Try with that solution.

Comment: oh, cool even don't know that we can create outlet for constraints) great. But maybe you know how to make it programmatically as well. thank you for answer)

Comment: I just set _searchBarHeight.constant = 0; and it also works for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a view the same size as the search bar and place the search bar inside. Set the top constraint equal to the top of the superview.
2. Create the custom view and set its top constraint equal to the first view bottom.
3. Add a height constraint to the first view and also create the rest of your constraints.

To hide the search bar, programmatically set the first view height constraint to 0 which will make the custom view top move to the top of the superview.  This can be animated too.

Comment: and if I set height constraint to 0 for search bar will it work? or I need to create additional view in any case and place there my search bar. Also can you set example of code how can I set height constraint to 0 programmatically? thank you

Comment: You could skip the first view and just use the UISearchBar.  To set the height constraint to 0 programmatically, create a NSLayoutConstraint property and connect that to the constraint created in IB.  _searchBarHeight.constant = 0;

Answer (score 0):

It should be look like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvheh.png

Blue-view should have constraints to top view and bottom constraint to purple view. Don't forget make height constraint for blue view.

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.heightConstraint.constant = 0;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```